# R: Simulate AR(2) setting variance of the series as initial values

Tags: r, arima

1. I am trying to simulate `ARIMA(2,0,0)` that follow this equation:
   [image: ARIMA(2,0,0) model]
2. I which to set the first two initial values to be the variance of `ARIMA(2,0,0)which are:

[image: ![variance of ARIMA(2,0,0)]

I have this `r` code to depict my interest:

```
n <- 50
phi1 <- 0.5 
phi2 <- -0.7
e <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1)
x1 <- sqrt((e[1])^2/(1-phi1^2))
x2 <- sqrt(((1-phi2^2)*e[1]^2)/((1-phi2)*((1-phi2)^2-phi1^2)))
set.seed(123)
ar1 <- arima.sim(n, model=list(ar=c(phi1, phi2)), start.innov=c(x1,x2), n.start=2, innov=c(0,0,e[-2]))
```

I want you to check through my `r` code to see if I am missing something.

Comment: I didn't look carefully but check out ?arima.sim for info start.innov and innov because I don't think you have those right. Where did you get the expressions for $x_1$ and $x_2$ ?

Comment: @mlofton `x1` is the standard deviation of `AR(1)` wile `x2` is the standard deviation of `AR(2)`

Comment: Do you want the series to start at the values x1 and x2? If so, the results from your code seem to not have that feature.

Comment: Also, based on your definitions for x1 and x2, it seems like you want to use the variance of $\varepsilon_t$, but you seem to be using a realization of it instead

Comment: I believe that $\sigma^2_{\varepsilon} \equiv \operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_t)$.

Comment: @SOULed_Outt I want x1 and x2 to be the starting values. Can you show me how the starting values will be x1 and x2

Comment: @SOULed_Outt Can you also show me what the variance should be especially in `R` code?

Comment: Usually for these types of models it is assumed that $\varepsilon_t \sim \mathcal N (0, 1)$, so if I'm correct in saying that $\sigma^2_{\varepsilon} \equiv \operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_t)$, then you would set $\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}$. In your code, you'd replace `e[1]` with `1`

Comment: I'm still unsure on how to set the starting values in the `arima.sim` function, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding an earlier comment, I'm assuming that $\sigma^2_\varepsilon \equiv \operatorname{Var} (\varepsilon_t)$. If that's true, then I've seen many cases where it's assumed that $\sigma^2_\varepsilon = 1$ and your code should update your code to

```
x1 <- sqrt(1/(1-phi1^2))
x2 <- sqrt((1-phi2^2)/((1-phi2)*((1-phi2)^2-phi1^2)))
```

I have no idea how the `arima.sim` function can handle specifying starting values. I did a little research and came across some [notes of Dr. Henrik Madsen for the simulation of AR processes](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/~hmad/time.series.analysis/assignments/simulation.stoch.processes.pdf). On pages 2 and 3 he says you can use the `filter` function to simulate the AR process.

So you have the process $x_t = 0.5 x_{t-1} - 0.7 x_{t-2} + \varepsilon_t$. From this recursive equation you have the following two equations for $x_1$ and $x_2$:
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 0.5 x_0 - 0.7 x_{-1} + \varepsilon_1 \\
x_2 &= 0.5 x_1 - 0.7 x_{0} + \varepsilon_2
\end{align} 
You can see that they depend on values $x_0$ and $x_{-1}$, which don't exist so the `filter` function treats them as zero and generates $$x_1 = \varepsilon_1$$ and $$x_2 = 0.5 \varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2$$

So you can "trick" it by generating a vector for the noise process, say $\left(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2, \ldots, \varepsilon_n \right)$, and alter the first and second component of the vector as follows:
$$\left(x_1,\: x_2-0.5x_1\:, \ldots, \varepsilon_n \right)$$.

For example, if $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = -2$ and $\varepsilon_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, 1)$ then you can use the following code:

```
n <- 50                       # length of series
x_1 <- 1                      # first initial value
x_2 <- -2                     # second initial value
phi <- c(0.5, -0.7)           # vector of autoregressive coefficients
e <- rnorm(n)                 # vector from standard normal noise process
e[1] <- x_1                   # updating so the first value of the series is x_1
e[2] <- x_2 - phi[1]*x_1      # updating so the second value of the series is x_2
ar2 <- filter(e, filter = phi, method = "recursive")
ar2

# output from code above
# [1]  1.00000000 -2.00000000 -1.74287046  1.89716706  1.94282186  1.15986460
# [7] -2.32879581 -1.39168937  1.05816662  1.71920744  0.49852657 -1.45650538
# ...
```

---

I've managed to reproduce the output above using the `arima.sim` function. But I must admit that I still don't truly understand how `start.innov` is handled in the function.

```
ar2.sim <- arima.sim(n, model=list(ar=c(phi[1], phi[2])), 
            start.innov=c(0, 0), n.start=2, 
            innov=c(x_1,x_2 - phi[1]*x_1 ,e[-c(1,2)]), sd = 1)
ar2.sim

# output from code above
# [1]  1.00000000 -2.00000000 -1.74287046  1.89716706  1.94282186  1.15986460
# [7] -2.32879581 -1.39168937  1.05816662  1.71920744  0.49852657 -1.45650538
# ...
```

Comment: I agree with you on your argument on `x1` and `x2` that `variance of the error term =1` on the ground that `e <- rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=1)` but using `filter` is not what I am considering for now

Comment: If $\sigma^2_\epsilon = \operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_t)$ then typically it assumed to be 1 (or just a constant in general). You haven't confirmed this to be true or false. It is based on an assumption for the AR(2) model, which should be known before the code is written.

Comment: Yes, `$var(\varepsilon_t)=\sigma_t^2$. I confirm.